# Why Chrome Dev Tools Console generates log entries in two different ways (single-line and multiline)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

The following code generates incremental single-line log in the Chrome Dev Tools console:

```
var run = function() {
  console.log('hello');
}    
setInterval(run, 250);
```

[image]

When I use lodash throttle wrapper I see multiline log:

```
var run = function() {
  console.log('hello');
}
var _run = _.throttle(run, 250);
setInterval(_run, 20);
```

[image]

All log entries link to the second source code line which is `console.log('hello');` in both versions. Why there is such a splitting for throttled logging?

Comment: You will have to read into the implementation of the Developer Tools to know exactly why.

Comment: What is the source code of `_.throttle`?

Comment: @guest271314 [Here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L10911) is the implementation of Lodash thottle method.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant specification

[2.3.2. Printer user experience innovation](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#optimally-useful-formatting)

- De-duplication of identical output to prevent spam.

  **Example**
  In this example, the implementation not only batches multiple identical messages, but also provides the number of messages that have been batched together.
  [image]

Workarounds for the example string passed to `.log()` include concatenating a variable number of space characters to the output to prevent duplicate content being recognized by the `.log()` function

```
var run = function() {
  console.log("hello".concat(" ".repeat(Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1)));
}    
setInterval(run, 250);
```

using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`

```
var run = function() {
 console.log("hello");
 setTimeout(run, 250);
}    
setTimeout(run, 250);
```

or using `console.table()`

```
var run = function() {
  console.table(["hello"]);
}    
setInterval(run, 250);
```

Comment: This is very strange: `setTimeout` version gives ~30 separate log entries and then unlimited number of joined single-line entries.

Comment: @dhilt Yes, noticed that as well. Did you scroll at DevTools using `setTimeout()` approach? Does the same occur using `_.throttle()`?

Comment: @dhilt At one point during testing it appears that scrolling at DevTools affected output, though cannot currently how to reproduce the steps.

Comment: @dhilt Another option, using CSS `var run = function() {
 console.log("hello%c" + Math.random(), "color:transparent;");
}    
setInterval(run, 250)`

Comment: The OP does not ask for a "workaround", he does ask why the deduplication does not happen in his example (despite arguably identical messages)

Comment: @Bergi The Answer explains why and cites the specification. The `_.throttle()` function uses timers, similar to `setTimeout()` approach at Answer. Have little experience using lodash. If you have a more detailed answer relevant to lodash `_.throttle()` function post the Answer. Else, your critique is rather useless, as it adds nothing of substance to the discussion other than indicating your perspective.

Comment: @guest271314 That text you cited is not authoritative, it's explicitly marked as an "example for an implementation-defined printing enhancement". And no, it does not explain why it does happen in the first but not in the second snippet.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the specification does clarify why the output is on a single line at first example of code at Question. The specification does not explain why the output is not the same at second example. It is this user which stated that it the different result is related to use of timers within `_.throttle()`, similar to `setTimeout()` example at Answer; that is the estimation from perspective here. Unless you can show and prove otherwise, which you should do at your own Answer so that we might all learn from your expertise in the field

Comment: @guest271314 Well that information ("*related to use of timers within _.throttle()*") should go in the answer, not in the comments. And you might want to remove the workaround with the space concatenation, it's not relevant at all.

Comment: @Bergi There is no issue with the Answer in the current form. Though if you have the sense that the Answer can be improved, by all means edit the Answer accordingly; or post your own Answer to affirmatively resolve the inquiry

Comment: I know how answering works, thank you. Please don't always try to derail our discussions, if you prefer not to take constructive feedback from me just tell me and I'll move on, spending downvotes anonymously without explaining your issues in the future.

Comment: @Bergi Do continue the constructive feedback